# Is it possible to display UIProgressView style rectangle on the background of UITextField?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to display UIProgressView style rectangle on the background of UITextField?
Just likes Safari's url bar displayed the progress when loading web page.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display any view but not as a background property, you can addIt like a sub view.

May be you need [UIActivityIndicatorView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    activityIndicatorView.frame = activityIndicatorFrame;

    [yourTextField addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
    [activityIndicatorView release];
```

There is no such style rectangle for UIProgressView.

```
UIProgressViewStyle
The styles permitted for the progress bar.

typedef enum {
   UIProgressViewStyleDefault,
   UIProgressViewStyleBar,
} UIProgressViewStyle;
Constants
UIProgressViewStyleDefault
The standard progress-view style. This is the default.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIProgressView.h.
UIProgressViewStyleBar
The style of progress view that is used in a toolbar.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIProgressView.h.
Discussion
You can set and retrieve the current style of progress view through the progressViewStyle property.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
UIProgressView.h
```